# How to use two ruby,rails version on same machine but different project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rbenv, ruby-on-rails-7

Right now I have a `project demo` on my `Desktop` with versions

```
Ruby-2.6.3p62
Rails-4.2.11.3
Gem-3.0.3
```

and I want to create an another `project new` on my `Desktop` with versions

```
ruby-3.1.1p18
Rails-7.0.2.3
Gem-3.3.13
```

and currently, I have this `rbenv` version

```
rbenv version
2.6.3 (set by /home/akshit/.rbenv/version)
```

Can you share the commands on how to create `project new` without affecting my `project demo`?

Comment: If you are already using rbenv adding `.ruby-version` to your projects root should do the trick

Comment: Just ensure you install the ruby versions and switching version should be taken care of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using rbenv do this:

- create `project new`
- open a terminal inside root folder
- write `rbenv install 3.1.1` and then `rbenv local 3.1.1` so for this project it will use the specified version

I suggest you to create a `.ruby-version` file where you set the project's ruby version, in this case 3.1.1

Comment: What is the .ruby-version file and how to create it? I run the two commands a i got this * 3.1.1 (set by /home/akshit/Desktop/new/.ruby-version)

Comment: It's just a file with the project's ruby version target that every ruby manager can understand. To create it just create a new file named `.ruby-version` and paste `3.1.1`